# What determines how long a HOLD invoice will be held before it times out and is forced on chain?

Tags: lightning-network, hash-time-locked-contract, invoices, channels, preimage

How long can a HOLD invoice be held before it times out and is forced on chain?

1. Is there a way for the receiver to define a minimum timeout requirement in the invoice in order for it to be successfully paid?
2. Is the sender able to know the timeout amount before or after sending?
3. Is the sender able to define the timeout amount before sending?
4. Is this timeout dependent on the route the sender selected?
5. Is the receiver able to determine the timeout amount once they have received the HTLC?
6. Is the timeout something that can be adjusted after a channel is opened or can it only be defined when a channel is opened?

Comment: @Murch, I don't appreciate you changing my question from `HOLD` to `HODL` invoice. `HODL` i the slang term. Please see the following examples where `HOLD` is used:

Comment: https://lightning.engineering/api-docs/api/lnd/invoices/add-hold-invoice

Comment: https://voltage.cloud/blog/lightning-network-faq/understanding-hold-invoices-on-the-lightning-network/

Comment: http://buildonln.com/advanced/hold_invoices.html

Comment: https://bitcoinops.org/en/topics/hold-invoices/

Comment: Mea culpa, I had only heard to it referred to as ["hodl invoice"](https://docs.lightning.engineering/community-resources/glossary#hodl-invoice) before. I’ve rolled back your post to your original variant

Comment: No problem, I think it helps to have both in the comments now for search ability since there is some people using both.